# Hide Folder Pane in CKFinder Popup

Tags: css, ckfinder

I've installed CKFinder on a website I'm developing and so far it's working pretty good. I have a "documents" page that has a standalone instance of CKFinder for managing files in all subfolders. However, I also have a product management page that allows a user to add images/files to a product listing with a CKFinder popup. When clicking browse next to an input field, it opens a CKFinder popup and points to the appropriate subfolder.

This is working great! However, I was wondering if it was possible to hide the folder pane inside the popup so that the user cannot accidentally choose the wrong subfolder. I see that CSS can be modified to hide the pane altogether, but I would like to be able to still use it from the main "documents" page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the following setting:
`displayFoldersPanel: false`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be just to set the sidebar pane width to 0 using `config.sidebarWidth = '0';` in config.js